# Is SSL needed for a public FTP server?

Tags: security, ftp, ssl, internet-security

I'm going to host a public FTP update server (vsftpd on CentOS 7). Devices (dvr recorders) connect to the server with username anonymous and no password to check wether they have the latest firmware. They can only download and not write.

New firmware is uploaded to the server using SSH. So there are no other FTP logins then the anonymous ones.

Is it still good to use SSL/TLS? Are there security risks without? Because that will make maintaining a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only good, it's necessity. Even more so, if you use the FTP to deliver software to devices of unknowing customers.

If you do not use TLS/SSL, anyone anywhere on the line between a device and the server can smuggle in a fake firmware, turning the devices into anything he/she wants.

Read about [Man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

---

*To be honest, if you have to ask such a question, you are not the right person to setup such a critical networking component.*

Comment: Note that if the asker used signed updates then this wouldn't strictly be true. That would limit it to DoS and privacy issues.